# how to set checkbox and spinner with repective values in android

Tags: android, checkbox, spinner

I am trying to manipulating checkbox and with respective spinner and sending value to next page.

Here, If first check asia check box and choose on of the country from the first called asia spinner. same as check europe also checked and choose one of the country from the europe spinner.

If i click setdetails button, then go to next page and set all deatils of both checked country. and filly save all countries deatils on database.

Here some sample pictures, that display my problem.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you provide spinner with an adapter to fill it's values which looks like this:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

To then get checked value you write:

```
String selectedParent = parentSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

To set the value you do this:

```
parentSpinner.setSelection(i);
```

where i is an index in the list you provided (i.e. 0 means "first element in the list").

To pass those values to the next activity you use set extras to Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(TaskViewActivity.this, TaskViewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("status", status);
TaskViewActivity.this.startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

To fetch them from the activity you called you do this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
task_id = extras.getLong("status");
```

I hope that helps!